# Write unit test for object.GetType().InvokeMember

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have method with uses object.GetType().InvokeMember():

```
private void InvokeComObject(object callback, object parameter)
        {
            callback.GetType().InvokeMember(
                                name: "[DispID=0]",
                                invokeAttr: BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                                binder: null,
                                target: callback,
                                args: new Object[] { parameter == null ? "" : parameter });
        }
```

and a unit test for it:

```
[Test]
public void should_execute_action()
{
    var executor = CreateExecutor();

    Action<int> callback = Substitute.For<Action<int>>();

    executor.ExecuteAction("name", "value", callback);

    callback.Received(1).GetType().InvokeMember(Arg.Is<string>(r => r == "[DispID=0]"), 
        Arg.Is<BindingFlags>(r => r.HasFlag(BindingFlags.Instance) && r.HasFlag(BindingFlags.InvokeMethod)), 
        Arg.Is<Binder>(r => r == null), Arg.Is<object>(r => ReferenceEquals(r, callback)), 
        Arg.Is<Object[]>(r => r == new Object[] { 2 }));
}
```

executor.ExecuteAction inside executes InvokeComObject with "callback" which I passed to this method. This methods fails with exception on "callback.Received(1).GetType().InvokeMember":
"System.ArgumentException: Must specify binding flags describing the invoke operation required (BindingFlags.InvokeMethod CreateInstance GetField SetField GetProperty SetProperty)."
How can I make this test work?

Comment: Well what's the exception?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I updated the question

Comment: Okay, that's slightly more useful. But I'm not sure you're going to be able to intercept `Type.InvokeMember`, basically... I think you'd be far better off coming up with an example that genuinely has the member you're invoking, rather than using mocking like this.

Comment: You should really just code a pure .net object which would have this member as a method (for the weird names, see Reflection.Emit) and then you can assert that the right parameters have been passed.